# 404 on images with special chars ($, €, etc.) in name

Tags: url, special-characters, filenames

I have image file on server named `2011-1-oz-Gold-Austrian-Philharmonic-€100-Bullion-Coin-.9999-24K-2sds.jpg`
but server returns `2011-1-oz-Gold-Austrian-Philharmonic-%E2%82%AC100-Bullion-Coin-.9999-24K-2sds.jpg` Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Why is this happening and how to make special characters are not screened

Comment: What is the 'server' ? an http server ? a tomcat server ? a jee server ? Do you have access or error logs ?

Comment: http server, all errors on client side? server logs don't have any info about problem.

Comment: You could provide some more information ... What is the http server ? Apache httpd, MS IIS, lighttpd, nginx ?

Comment: It's Apache, A friend told me that the problem with file encoding and need to change it using iconv.

Comment: iconv can change the content of the file, your problem is the file **name**, did you search other questions ? I came accross this http://serverfault.com/questions/449134/apache-url-filename-with-special-characters

Comment: We decided batch rename files and it's signatures on server